# Text field should not accept Zero or Negative values? Only positive values are allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

Text field should not accept Zero or Negative values.

As it is an amount field it should accept only positive values are allowed.

my sample code is here:

```
<td><spring:message code="amount"/><spring:message code="label.mandatory"/></td>
<td><form:input path="amount" /></td>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to have a form control with a name of *name* as it will shadow the form's own *name* property. Also, the change event occurs after the value has changed and the input loses focus. Changing the value programatically won't trigger a change event.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of a control programatically doesn't dispatch a change event, so either put that logic as part of whatever is changing the value, or dispatch a change event yourself.

It may be better to set the default value of the name input (which seems an inappropriate name if it has a number value and especially if the form has a name) to zero and make it readonly. Also, move the code into a function. But here's a solution based on your original:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="0" readonly>
<input type="button" value="up" onclick="
  this.form.name.value = ++this.form.name.value;
">
<input type="button" value="down" onclick="
  var el = this.form.name;
  var value = el.value;
  el.value  = value < 1? 0 : --value;
">
```

Note that the values of form controls are strings, so be careful with using the `+` operator. It will do concatenation instead of addition if you aren't careful.